# Error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript

Tags: c++

I want to type this form in my program: s1[k[I]], but it doesn't let me. How can I fix this? Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    string s1[N];
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++)
    {
        cin >> s1[k];
    }
    int counter=0;
    for(int k=0;k<N-1;k++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<s1[k].size();k++)
        {
            if(s1[k[i]] == s1[k[i]])
            {
                cout << s1[k][i] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't spam different languages in the tags. This looks like C++, so I'm going to remove the others

Comment: What is `k[i]` supposed to do?  Ask yourself: What is the type of `k`?

Comment: What should `k[i]` mean, when `k` is declared as `int k=0;`?

Comment: `k` is not an array so `s[k[i]]` makes no sense, did you mean `s1[k][i]` like you wrote on the next line?

Comment: Another question to ask yourself, whatever you actually meant by `s1[k[i]]` when would it ever not be the case that `s1[k[i]]==s1[k[i]]`? You are compaing to identical expressions with each other, that's always going to be true.

Comment: Also obligatory link to the question about [variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) which you use with `string s1[N];`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the index (`[]`) operator is generally for arrays. But in this statement: `if(s1[k[i]]==s1[k[i]])`, `k` is an `int`, not an `int[]`. So how can you index an integer?

Additional: Don't use `using namespace std;` as it isn't a good practice.

Comment: @S.M. Yeah geez how did I not see it. Thanks for pointing out! I gotta make more coffee ;)

Comment: Thanks, for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you tried to join different ideas that don't realy want work together, mixing char arrays and std::strings can be done but is a no good idea because is messy.

As you can see in the example, use the std::string as intended and that's it.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int N, i;

    std::cout << "Add a number -> ";
    std::cin  >> N;

    std::cout << "Add a string -> ";
    std::string string;
    std::cin >> string;


    // recomended method
    std::cout << "From std::string -> " << N << " | "  << string << std::endl;


    char * char_vec = new char [string.length()];
    memcpy(char_vec, string.c_str(), sizeof(char) * string.length());

    std::cout << "From array -> " << N << " | ";
    for(i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
        std::cout << char_vec[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    delete [] char_vec;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer